# Assign "and userName in('kuldeep')" to variable and add to query then execute

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have some code like:

```
declare @Condition nvarchar(50), --value  'and user_name in ('deep') 
select * from table where id = 10
```

After `10` I want to put `@Condition` value. How to assign and put it?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you even looked into BOL TSQL coding basics, before asking here?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SET @local_variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259193%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

```
SET { { @local_variable = expression } 
    | { @cursor_variable = { @cursor_variable | cursor_name 
            | { CURSOR [ FORWARD_ONLY | SCROLL ] 
                [ STATIC | KEYSET | DYNAMIC | FAST_FORWARD ] 
                [ READ_ONLY | SCROLL_LOCKS | OPTIMISTIC ] 
                [ TYPE_WARNING ] 
            FOR select_statement 
                [ FOR { READ ONLY | UPDATE [ OF column_name [ ,...n ] ] } 
                ] 
            } 
    } } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a string that contains SQL as part of a query you need the `EXECUTE` statement.

```sql
DECLARE @Condition NVARCHAR(50) = 'AND user_name IN (''deep'')';

EXECUTE( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 10 ' + @Condition );
```